# Use a Node module in a public JS file in a Laravel app

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to use https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap in my Laravel app.

I did an `npm install @tiptap/core @tiptap/starter-kit` and the modules are installed fine and visible in my `node_modules` folder. Then, I added

```
import { Editor } from '@tiptap/core'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
```

to my `resources/js/apps.js` and ran an `npm run dev`. I can see some tiptap code in my `public/js/app.js` file.

I would like to instantiate a tiptap class from another public JS file:

- which didn't come out of webpack
- which I declared with a `<script type="module" src="{{ asset('js/tiptap.js') }}"></script>` in my Blade file
- which contains following:

```
import { Editor } from '@tiptap/core'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'

new Editor({
  element: document.querySelector('.element'),
  extensions: [
    StarterKit,
  ],
  content: '<p>Hello World!</p>',
})
```

but I just get a `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@tiptap/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` in the console.

So yeah, wrong path for the import most likely. I tried to change it to `'./app.js@tiptap/core'` and other variations but always end up with a `404 Not found`.

I feel like I'm maybe doing the wrong way maybe, I don't know. Would you guys have any tips on how to do that ?

Comment: would you like to share resources, and public folder structure?

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo I have a typical Laravel folder structure. What would you need to know?

Comment: If you're using webpack its much easier just adding the tiptap.js to the resources folder and adding it to webpack.
Why do you want to add it to a js file that doesn't come out of webpack?

Comment: @JohnZwarthoed because I need to instantiate classes of the package from a Blade file and I don't know how to do that if the classes are inside the bundled app.js file so I'm putting all my JS code in public files directly to circumvent that... I saw that you can prefix function with "window." before Webpack so that they would be available globally after but it seems kind of hacky to me to put window. everywhere in my code.

Comment: asset() function takes the argument as a relative path from public or resources, so check tiptap.js path where can you find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a package from outside because when `webpack` built it for you it encapsulates the file as a `bundle` so to be able to access it you could create another `js` file in the `resources/js` after that include it inside the `app.js` to be bundled with `webpack` like this

```
// hello.js
console.log("welcome from hello script")

// app.js
require('./hello.js')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So just to be sure, what you're saying is that I can only call the package classes from a JS file in resources/js ?

Comment: yes , for sure.